# Installing the Media Module + WYSIWYG Module on Acquia Cloud

Tags: wysiwyg, media, acquia-cloud

I'm trying to get the Media module (and it's dependent WYSIWYG module) working on an Acquia Cloud environment. Normally, this isn't too bad locally but Acquia has a strange file structure that is giving me some headaches.

I have installed and activated both WYSIWYG along with Media but neither are working correctly. WYSIWYG needs CKEditor to work and wants it to be included in `sites/all/libraries` (outside of the normal modules folder). Acquia doesnt give you access to add in libraries like that.

Media isn't showing the library when a user accesses a content-type with an image field that use's Media's 'Media file selector' widget.

Im guessing a lot of this is due to path problems, but the only documentation Acquia has about their file structure is here (and this mostly pertains to the files folder - not core + contrib paths):
https://docs.acquia.com/cloud/files

So my question is two fold:

- How do you get CKEditor into an Acquia Cloud instance with the WYSIWYG module?
- Why wouldnt media show its library? Am I leaving another module out maybe? Path issue?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: turn off livedev in your Acquia Cloud dev environment.

Longer Answer: I was trying to drush my modules and do basic site building in their environment using the livedev option. But they don't let you run `mkdir` and `scp` live in their environment via CLI.

Their recommended workflow will have you add your modules/libraries locally, commit via git and then push up to their environment.